# Concatenate elements of a list in c#

Tags: c#

I wanted to try some examples in C# using collections and generics but I am stuck at this example.

This is my code in c#,

```
public List<string> CurrentCount(int week, int year)
{
      List<string> lst = new List<string>();
      lst.Add("current:");
      lst.Add("10");
      lst.Add("target:");
      lst.Add("15");

   return lst;
}

It gives me result like this : 
["current:","10","target:","15"]

But I want it like this : 
["current": 10,"target": 15] or
["current": "10","target": "15"]
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something that stores ordered pairs. A dictionary works well for that.

Comment: Nirav, does your code anyhow related with json serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), not a `List`.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("current", 10);
dict.Add("target", 15);
```

Comment: I got the result like this : [{"Key":"current:","Value":"10"},{"Key":"target:","Value":"15"}]. I don't want to display "key" and "value".

Comment: Well, it depends on how you're outputting the data. how about something like: `foreach(var keyValuePair in dict){Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);}`